# Change letter with number

Tags: c

I'm doing an exercise, to practice, where the point is to receive a string of numbers and letters, check if it's a letter, transforme it to number with the rule

```
A = 10, Z = 35
```

and then place everything in an array. Some operations after.

I know how to do everything except the rule part, no idea about how to check which letter it is and how to replace it with the right number. I know there's a way with something like

```
     if(string[x] == 'a-Z')
```

but i'm neither sure how that works, or how to pick the right number knowing that it's a letter.

Comment: Are you wanting to convert char to int? or get the characters spot in the alphabet? `char f = 'a'; if (f >= 'a' && f <= 'Z') { // it is a letter }` I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with a c string?

Comment: Convert char to int. It checks the string character by character, and converts it to int in case it's a letter.

Comment: If i only wanted to check if it's a letter i could use isalpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches, some more portable than others.

The following looks for the`string[x]` in an array.  If successful, the pointer difference  between it and the start is the value.

```
const char *alphanum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char *p = strchr(alphanum, string[x]);
if (p == NULL || *p == '\0') {
  ; // Not a digit or A-Z
} else {
  int value = p - alphanum;
  // do something with the value;      
}
```

I'll leave handling of `a-z` to the OP.  (convert to upper or use another array)

If code assumes ASCII, with  its `A Z` in sequential order:

```
int ToValue(char ch) {
  if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') return ch - 'A' + 10;
  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') return ch - 'a' + 10;
  if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
  // No match
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the ToValue function? i don't understand the return

Comment: @André Almeida  When `ToValue('A')` is called, it returns the value of `10`.   `ToValue('z')` --> `35`, `ToValue('0')` --> `0`, `ToValue('#')` --> `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to divide functions like that into more functions that deal with smaller pieces of logic.

```
int isLowerCaseLetter(char c)
{
   return ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int isUpperCaseLetter(char c)
{
   return ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

int letterToNumber(char c)
{
   if ( isdigit(c) )
   {
      return (c - '0');
   }
   else if ( isLowerCaseLetter(c) )
   {
      return (c - 'a' + 10);
   }
   else if ( isUpperCaseLetter(c) )
   {
      return (c - 'A' + 10);
   }

   // Problem

   assert(0);
   return 0; // Keep the compiler happy
}
```